# Cold emailing professors as a potential doctoral student 2024

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, advisor, engineering

I graduated with a B.Sc in Robotics and Mechatronics Engineering from the University of Dhaka, Bangladesh. I am planning to apply for Ph.D. programs for the spring/fall 2024 intake. My research interests include in the application of 3D computer vision, Deep learning and deep reinforcement learning.

I've been emailing potential supervisors in the US for if they have any vacancies in their lab/research group for the past one month. So far, only three professors have replied, one of them gave a generic reply and the other two professors said they will not be taking new students next year.

Can anyone point out anything that I'm doing wrong? Or suggest me some better way with anything? Also feel free to roast my profile, my resume or anything you don't feel is right! Or anything else that might help me in improving my profile. I would really appreciate it

For your reference:

###### [Here's my personal website][1]

###### [Here's my resume][2]

###### [Here's a sample of the email I've sent][3]

Comment: Could you kindly redact (sanitise) your sample emails.

Comment: done, thank you

Comment: Sorry, i missed that, I redacted that too. I'm not really asking for evaluating my website/resume here. I just posted them in context so it might be easier for someone to advise me. Thank you for the feedback though

Comment: What you need to do is to take TOEFL/IELTS, maybe GRE, then apply for PhD programs for Fall, 2024. The profs will not offer you RA unless you're their student.

Comment: I am scheduled to take IELTS next week and GRE on the 18th of September

Comment: [We have a number of relevant previous threads.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=cold+emailing)

Comment: Let me say this. The profs have not seen your transcript, your ILTS score and recommendation letters, there is no way they will give you good reply regardless how well your e-mail is written. I think you should forget about the email, concentrate on the IELTS/GRE test right now.

Comment: VTC as if we took a question asking for evaluation of an individual's materials, it would seem that that is acceptable, which it is not. Also, I don't think "spring intake" is very common or exists at all.